# Salvando uma informação no mesmo atributo de banco de dados usando duas textbox

Tags: c#

Eu queria saber se tem como eu salvar duas informações diferentes em um mesmo atributo no banco de dados. Tipo eu tenho dois textbox, um cpf e outro cnpj. Eu queria salvar o cpf e o cnpj junto. Só que eu criei duas textbox, uma pra cada um.

Código do model

```
public int idClientefisico { get; set; } 
public string nome { get; set; } 
public string rg { get; set; } 
public string cpf { get; set; } 
public string email { get; set; } 
public string endereco { get; set; } 
public string nr { get; set; } 
public string cep { get; set; } 
public string estado { get; set; } 
public string telefone { get; set; } 
public string cidade { get; set; } 

public void Insert(Model.cliente_fisico clientefisico) 
{ 
    SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(strCon);
    string sql = @"Insert into cliente_fisico values 
                  (@nome,@rg,@cpf,@email,@endereco,@nr,@cep,@estado,@telefone,@cidade)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexao);     
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", clientefisico.nome); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rg", clientefisico.rg); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", clientefisico.cpf); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", clientefisico.email); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endereco", clientefisico.endereco); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nr", clientefisico.nr); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cep", clientefisico.cep); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", clientefisico.estado); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefone", clientefisico.telefone); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cidade", clientefisico.cidade); 

    conexao.Open(); 

    try 
    { 
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Deu erro na inserção de Cliente do tipo fisico ... ");
    }
    finally
    {
        conexao.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Não deu pra entender nada, sério. Você pode [edit] sua publicação e tentar deixá-la mais clara.

Comment: ficou mais claro?

Comment: Tem como fazer isso sim. Era isso que queria saber?

Comment: Sim, eu gostaria de saber o modo que é pois ai eu criaria uma outra tabela pra armazenar só dois tipos de dados diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, tem como fazer isso com técnicas simples. Veja esse exemplo usando apenas uma classe de ViewModel:

```
public class CadastroViewModel
{
    // outras propriedades
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public string Documento
    {
        get { return CPF ?? CNPJ; }
        set 
        { 
            if (ID.Length < 14)
                CPF = Documento;
            else
                CNPJ = Documento;
        }
    }
}
```

Assim, você atribui valores dos TextBoxes em CPF e CNPJ, mas sempre salva e recupera do banco a propriedade Documento.

Comment: Meu código está logo acima, não deu pra colocar aqui.

Comment: Legal, agora vc adicionou. Basta vc substituir os campos `cpf` e `cnpj` na sua tabela por apenas um chamado `documento`. E gravar a propriedade `Documento` do meu exemplo.

Comment: @TMBruhTH Você não deve colocar o seu código na publicação do Thiago. Você precisa mantê-lo no corpo da sua pergunta.

Comment: No caso esse ID, seria o documento meu amigo?

Comment: @TMBruhTH, sim, eu já editei o exemplo, deve ficar mais claro agora.

Comment: o código do meu botão gravar, então ira ficar assim                 cliente_fisico.documento = txtCPF.Text;
                cliente_fisico.documento = txtCNPJ.Text;

Comment: @TMBruhTH, não, o oposto. Está na minha resposta: **"você atribui valores dos TextBoxes em CPF e CNPJ, mas sempre salva e recupera do banco a propriedade Documento."**